# Jackson annotations - ignore/overwirte inherited/parent annotation

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I have a parent class where one of the fields is annotated with `@JsonSerialize(using=CustomSerializer.class)`.

I have two other classes that inherit from the above parent, where in one of the child classes I'm OK with the custom serializer specified in the above annotation, but the other child should either ignore or overwrite `@JsonSerialize` as I don't want any custom serialization on the second child.
Is it possible to do this?